# Computing the derivative of $Axx^TB^T$ with respect to $x$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

I want to compute the derivative of

\begin{align}
f(x) = Axx^\top B^\top \label{eqn}
\end{align}

with respect to $x$ where $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $x$ is a (column) vector of size $n \times 1$. By this I mean the derivative of each component of $f(x)$ with respect to each component of $x$.

I can prove that if 
$$
g(x) = xx^\top
$$

Then the derivative can be expressed as,
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = x \otimes I_n + I_n \otimes x
$$
where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. In here I am
vectorizing $xx^\top$  and then taking the derivative with respect
to each of the components of $x$.

**Question:** Is there a way to extend this result to $f(x)$. My gut feeling is that this
should be possible. Any thoughts?. If that's not possible
how do I go about computing it?

**EDIT** (After Rodrigo de Azevedo's comment): You are right. But I mean the derivative in the following *flattened* sense. I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Let us consider the $2 \times 2$ case. Then $ Y =f(x)$ is a $2 \times 2$
matrix. If I *vectorize* $f(x)$ then I can view $f$ as,
$$
f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4
$$
More precisely
\begin{align}
f:
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1 \\
  x_2
\end{bmatrix} \to
  \begin{bmatrix}
    Y_{11} \\
    Y_{21} \\
    Y_{12} \\
    Y_{22}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Then by the symbol $\frac{\partial{f(x)}}{\partial{x}}$ I mean the
following:
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial{f(x)}}{\partial{x}}
  & =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \frac{\partial{Y_{11}}}{\partial{x_1}} &
      \frac{\partial{Y_{11}}}{\partial{x_2}} \\
      \frac{\partial{Y_{21}}}{\partial{x_1}} &
      \frac{\partial{Y_{21}}}{\partial{x_2}} \\
      \frac{\partial{Y_{12}}}{\partial{x_1}} &
      \frac{\partial{Y_{12}}}{\partial{x_2}} \\
      \frac{\partial{Y_{22}}}{\partial{x_1}} &
      \frac{\partial{Y_{22}}}{\partial{x_2}}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: So $x$ is a column vector, right?

Comment: Yes $x$ is indeed a column vector.

Comment: Differentiating a matrix-valued function with respect to a vector produces a 3-dimensional "matrix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the derivative of $f$ is the linear map $Df(x):v\mapsto Avx^TB^T + Axv^TB^T$. Using the identity $\operatorname{vec}(XYZ)=(Z^T\otimes X)\operatorname{vec}(Y)$, we get
\begin{align}
\operatorname{vec}(Avx^TB^T + Axv^TB^T)
&=\operatorname{vec}(Avx^TB^T) + \operatorname{vec}(Axv^TB^T)\\
&=[(Bx)\otimes A]\operatorname{vec}(v) + [B\otimes(Ax)]\operatorname{vec}(v^T)\\
&=[(Bx)\otimes A+B\otimes(Ax)]v.
\end{align}
Therefore the Jacobian matrix of $f$ is $(Bx)\otimes A + B\otimes(Ax)$.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?. How do I see that the derivative of $f$ is the linear map as given in the first equation?

Comment: @minibuffer It follows from the definition of derivative. $f(x+v)-f(x)=Avx^TB^T+Axv^T+B^T$ plus a second-order term in $v$. Therefore $Df(x)(v)=Avx^TB^T+Axv^T+B^T$.

Comment: The Jacobian can be written, without the commutation matrix, as $$(Bx)\otimes A + B\otimes(Ax)$$

Comment: You've calculated $(Ax\otimes B)$. My comment is that $K(Ax\otimes B)$ can be written without the commutator matrix as $(B\otimes Ax)$.

Comment: @greg Oh, you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let matrix-valued function $\mathrm F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be defined by

$$\mathrm F (\mathrm x) := \mathrm A \mathrm x \mathrm x^\top \mathrm B^\top$$

where $\mathrm A, \mathrm B \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ are given. The $(i,j)$-th entry of $\rm F$ is a *scalar* field given by

$$f_{ij} (\mathrm x) := \mathrm e_i^\top \mathrm A \mathrm x \mathrm x^\top \mathrm B^\top \mathrm e_j = \mathrm a_i^\top \mathrm x \mathrm x^\top \mathrm b_j = \mathrm x^\top \mathrm b_j \mathrm a_i^\top \mathrm x$$

where $\mathrm a_i^\top$ and $\mathrm b_j^\top$ are the $i$-th and $j$-th **rows** of matrices $\rm A$ and $\rm B$. [Hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2594270/339790), the gradient of $f_{ij}$ is

$$\nabla f_{ij} = \color{blue}{\left( \mathrm a_i \mathrm b_j^\top + \mathrm b_j \mathrm a_i^\top \right) \mathrm x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct, the known derivative
$$\eqalign{
G &= xx^T \\
g &= {\rm vec}(G) = x\otimes x \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= x\otimes I + I\otimes x \\
}$$
*can be* used to calculate the new derivative. Just take care to distinguish between a matrix and its flattened vector form.

The calculation is straightforward.
$$\eqalign{
F &= Axx^TB^T \\&= AGB^T \\
f &= {\rm vec}(F) \\&= (B\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(G) \\&= (B\otimes A)\,g \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= (B\otimes A)\;\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \\
 &= (B\otimes A)\;(x\otimes I + I\otimes x) \\
 &= (Bx\otimes AI) + (BI\otimes Ax) \\
 &= (Bx\otimes A) + (B\otimes Ax) \\
}$$